# write Conditional Multiplication logic in array of mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a json data as follows:

```
   [{
     finale: [ { sign: '~', prob: 0.5 }, 
               { sign: '~', prob: 0.4 } ] 
    },
    {
     finale: [ { sign: '~', prob: 0.7 }, 
               { sign: '>', prob: 0.25 } ] 
    }]
```

Now what I want with the result would be something like this:

```
 [{
   result : {
             sign: '~', prob: 0.2 
            }
  },
  {
   result : {
             sign: '>', prob: 0.25 
            }     
  }]
```

Here's my logic for the derivation:

If the array elements in the 'finale' have all "~" in the 'sign' element, then I want the result to have the multiplication of all of the 'prob' fields in the array which happens to be:

```
 0.5 * 0.4 = 0.2
```

However, if there's at least one sign that is either '>' or '<' I just need to copy the exact same thing from both the 'sign' and 'prob' in the result ignoring all other values as shown in the second result above

> [Note: there can only be one of the '<' or '>' in an array.  The array elements inside the 'finale' can have at most 3 elements but it should have at least 1 element. The ordering of the elements can also be random.]

Comment: is your array ordered? I mean, "<" and ">" is always after "~"?

Comment: is your array limited on 2 elements?

Comment: @Dada No there won't be any order in the array and the array can have at most 3 elements and at least 1 element. I know it sounds too complicated right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using **MongoDB Aggregation Framework.**

This query work with this limitation:
in each document cannot exists more then 1 "<" or 1 ">". Basically each object can have multiple "~" but 0 or 1 ">" or "<".

The main point is to group by sign, then reject every object has "~" except the case that it has only "~".

```
db.Test1.aggregate([
{
  $unwind:"$finale"
},
{
  $group:{
    _id: {_id: "$_id", sign:"$finale.sign"},
    finaleitems:{$push:"$finale"}
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    $or: [
       {$and:[  {finaleitems: {$size: 1}}, {$or:[   {"_id.sign":">"}, {"_id.sign":"<"}  ]}  ]},
       {$or:[  {finaleitems: {$size: 2}}, {finaleitems: {$size: 3}}     ]}
    ]
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    finaleitems: 1,
    result: {
      $cond: [{$eq:["$_id.sign","~"]}, 

      {
        $reduce: {
        input: "$finaleitems",
        initialValue: 1,
        in: { $multiply : ["$$value", "$$this.prob"] }
       }   
      }, 

      {$arrayElemAt:["$finaleitems",0]}]
    }
  }
}
]);
```

**INPUT**:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58033a8bd63cf401292fe09a"), 
    "finale" : [
        {
            "sign" : "~", 
            "prob" : 0.5
        }, 
        {
            "sign" : "~", 
            "prob" : 0.4
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58033a98d63cf401292fe09d"), 
    "finale" : [
        {
            "sign" : "~", 
            "prob" : 0.7
        }, 
        {
            "sign" : ">", 
            "prob" : 0.25
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58035251d63cf401292fe0a0"), 
    "finale" : [
        {
            "sign" : "<", 
            "prob" : 0.7
        }, 
        {
            "sign" : "~", 
            "prob" : 0.25
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5803622dd63cf401292fe0a3"), 
    "finale" : [
        {
            "sign" : "~", 
            "prob" : 0.7
        }, 
        {
            "sign" : ">", 
            "prob" : 0.25
        }
    ]
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5803622dd63cf401292fe0a3"), 
        "sign" : ">"
    }, 
    "finaleitems" : [
        {
            "sign" : ">", 
            "prob" : 0.25
        }
    ], 
    "result" : {
        "sign" : ">", 
        "prob" : 0.25
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58035251d63cf401292fe0a0"), 
        "sign" : "<"
    }, 
    "finaleitems" : [
        {
            "sign" : "<", 
            "prob" : 0.7
        }
    ], 
    "result" : {
        "sign" : "<", 
        "prob" : 0.7
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58033a98d63cf401292fe09d"), 
        "sign" : ">"
    }, 
    "finaleitems" : [
        {
            "sign" : ">", 
            "prob" : 0.25
        }
    ], 
    "result" : {
        "sign" : ">", 
        "prob" : 0.25
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58033a8bd63cf401292fe09a"), 
        "sign" : "~"
    }, 
    "finaleitems" : [
        {
            "sign" : "~", 
            "prob" : 0.5
        }, 
        {
            "sign" : "~", 
            "prob" : 0.4
        }
    ], 
    "result" : 0.2
}
```

As you can see there are more property returned, you don't need them but i think is good for debugging what the pipeline is producing.

I'm using Mongo DB 3.4RC that has `$reduce` function:
https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/

Hope that this resolve your issue.